# Large distance between two adjacent <h...> elements

Tags: html, css

I have noticed when I have a `<h2>` tag directly below an `<h1>` tag there is a large gap between the two. No padding or margin is set and I've normalised the css using normalize.css. Why does this gap exist?

Fiddle here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eK823/)

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

**html** (normalize.css is active on this html)

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Portfolio of...</h1>    
        <h2>Jing Xue</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

/* header ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.header h1 {
    font-family: 'Delius Swash Caps', cursive;
    font-size: 250%;
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
    /* margin-bottom: -50px; */
}

.header h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
    font-size: 450%;
    color: rgb(59,67,68);
}
```

---

**Further Question**

For what ever the reason for this big gap between "portfolio of..." and "Jing Xue", is the correct way to reduce the gap to give a negative top/bottom margin on the corresponding `<h..>`?

Comment: Note that normalize.css [*isn't* a CSS reset](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/). It preserves common, useful stylings, like the margins on header elements.

Comment: @Jamie, to give a negative amount you'd just use margin-top:-10px for example on the h2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`h1` through `h4` tags have a default margin. You need to remove that margin in your CSS.

```
.header h1 {
    font-family: 'Delius Swash Caps', cursive;
    font-size: 250%;
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
    margin:0;
}

.header h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
    font-size: 450%;
    color: rgb(59,67,68);
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour for these elements..

You forgot to take the default `margin-top` off of your `h2` element. Simply add `margin-top:0px;` to your `h2` class.

**Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eK823/1/)**.

Your class should now look like below:

```
.header h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
    font-size: 450%;
    color: rgb(59,67,68);
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Here is an image from **[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)** regarding some default styles of elements:

[image]

**See more about default styles of elements here on [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).**